# FTP from server to server not working

Tags: ftp, server, connection

I'm trying to transfer large amount of files from server A to server B. I've set up FTP (with FileZilla) on A.

When I try to connect to A from my PC it works perfectly.
But when I try to connect to A from B it doesn't work.
The FTP user logs in, but directory listing command keeps stuck.

Firewall port 21 is open. I've tried with several servers, different FTP clients but no avail. Besides FileZilla I also tried with ISS built in FTP service and got the same results.

Connects from local with the same credentials perfectly. But server to server connection is not working.

Server: Win 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5

Any ideas? Thanks in advence.

Comment: You are trying A from PC and its working. Perhaps via FileZilla but how you are access A from B?

Comment: B to A via Filezilla, Browser, many other clients... do not work.

Comment: What error you are seeing? can you copy paste it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FTP and FTPS use two channels for communication - a control channel, and a data channel. When you pass credentials (username and password), you are communicating on the control channel, typically port 21.

**Edit** (to clarify Active vs. Passive client configurations):

Then one of two things happens, depending on whether your FTP/S client is configured for Active or Passive data connections. If your client is configured for Active connections, the client will ask the server to communicate on port 20 for the data channel (or other port specified by the client).

If your client is configured for Passive connections, the client will defer to the server for the port to use for the data channel. The FTP server then tells the client which port to use for the data channel.

If this second port is blocked or restricted, your data communications - like directory listings - will fail.

Determine whether your FTP/s client is using Active or Passive configuration and that the respective port (port 20 for active configuration) is open.

For Passive configuration, check your FTP server configuration for the port it's using for the data channel. You can likely set it, as it may default to a random high port.

I understand that you're using Windows 2012 R2, and this TechNet post says it's for earlier Windows Server versions, but it gives a good explanation of what I'm trying to describe.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd464003(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: This solved the problem. We defined port range for passive mode and gave permission to those ports. This was before I saw your answer but thank you a lot anyway.

Comment: @Blameself Great, nice work. I'm glad to hear that you got it working.